# Regex and input validation Bash

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to validate user input

```
if ! [[ "$operator" =~ ("[+-/*]") ]] ; then     # validate user input to include decimals
        exec >&2; echo "error: Not a valid number, please try again";
        echo
else
        break
        echo
fi
```

Tried numerous combinations and not working? Ypu help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to accept numbers, as the comment and output imply, or operators, as the regex implies?

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

- Lose the quotes and parentheses around the regex; they're considered part of the regex. The quotes around `$operator` aren't needed either in this context, though they do no harm.
- `-` is a special character within `[]`, for use in stuff like `a-z`. Put it as first or last character to work around this.

So:

```
if ! [[ $operator =~ [-+/*] ]] ; then
```

I think it's customary to write `!` inside the `[[ ]]`, but either works.

Comment: The ! Negation outside the [[ ]] negates everything inside them eg ! [[ -d file || -r file ]] is different to [[ ! -d file || -r file ]]

Answer (score 0):

```
if ! [[ "$operator" =~ [-+]?[0-9]* ]] ; then
  ...
  ...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ cat validate.sh 
OPERATOR=$1
REGEX='[+*-/]';
if ! [[ $OPERATOR =~ $REGEX ]]; then
        echo "Not valid input"
else
        echo "Valid input"
fi

sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ bash validate.sh '-'
Valid input

sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ bash validate.sh '*'
Valid input

sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ bash validate.sh '/'
Valid input

sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ bash validate.sh '+'
Valid input

sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ bash validate.sh 's'
Not valid input

sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ bash validate.sh '132'
Not valid input
```